# How can I convert a list of values into an index/slice from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list that contains many elements, where each element represents an input file, that I want to dynamically subset using the values contained within another list. For example, I have some code that dynamically generates lists that I want to use to define the sub-samples such as

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I want to use the start and end elements of each of these lists to define an slice range to be applied to another list. In other words, I want the two above lists to be converted into slices that look like this

`[0:3]`
and  `[1:4]`

But I don't know how to do this, and to be honest I'm not even sure the correct terminology to use to search for this.  I have tried searching stack overflow for 'dynamically generate slices from lists' or even 'dynamically generate data slice' (an variants that I can think of along those lines) without any success.

Here are a few more details:

```
thislist = ['2019/12/26/fjjd', '2019/12/26/defg', '2020/01/09/qpfd', '2020/01/09/tosf', '2020/01/16/zpqr', '2020/01/15/zpqr', '2020/01/15/juwi']
```

where someIndexSlice is
`[0:3]`
and generated from a list that looks like this
`[0,1,2,3]`

```
thislist[someIndexSlice] = ['2019/12/26/fjjd', '2019/12/26/defg', '2020/01/09/qpfd', '2020/01/09/tosf']
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I accomplish this?
2. What sort of terminology should I use to describe what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks

Comment: The question is why you need to convert them into slices? Can you not index *the other list* with these numbers? Since you tag pandas, you would be fine with `df.loc[[0,1,2,3]]`.

Comment: What actual output do you want? `[0:3]` by itself is a syntax error.

Comment: It's a good idea, I did flag it with pandas but after looking more closely at the data structures I have, I could do it with a dataframe, but it's cumbersome.  I've removed the pandas tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) function:

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> as_slice = slice(lst[0], lst[-1], lst[1] - lst[0])
>>> as_slice
slice(0, 3, 1)        # which is same as [0:3]
```

And then to check if it works correctly:

```
>>> test = [1, 5, 3, 7, 8]
>>> test[as_slice]
[1, 5, 3]
>>> test[0:3]
[1, 5, 3]
```

**NOTE:**
This implementation assumed your `list`s are equidistant, and sorted.